# factorize complex polynom without guessing

Tags: complex-analysis

How would you approach to factorize $$P(x) = x^6-8$$

Normally I would use the approach of guessing $x-1$, $x+1$ etc. but this doesn't work. How do you reason to solve this?

Comment: I'd first note it can be written as $(x^2)^3-2^3$.

Comment: [Special Factoring: Factoring Sums and Differences of Cubes & Recognizing Perfect Squares](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/specfact2.htm)

Comment: I find this question vague. Apparently you're asking about general techniques to factor some polynomials. But which kind of polynomials? Those that look like $z^n-\alpha$? Or some other kind?

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$x^6 - 8 = (x^2)^3 - 2^3 = (x^2-2)(x^4 + 2x^2 + 4) = (x - \sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})((x^2+1)^2 +3)^2 = ....$$

Comment: except that $x^4+2x^2+4\ne (x^2+2)^2$.